# One to many Bidirectional not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, `DevolucionProveedor` and `ArticuloDefectuoso`, these have a relation OneToMany from `DevolucionProveedor` to `ArticuloDefectuoso`.

When I try create a new DevolucionProveedor and try add one or many entities `ArticuloDefectuoso`, these are not associated.

This is my relation:

```
#ArticuloDefectuoso

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\DevolucionProveedor", inversedBy="articulosDefectuosos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="devolucionProveedor", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $devolucionProveedor;

    //Methods

    /**
     * Set devolucionProveedor
     *
     * @param \CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\DevolucionProveedor $devolucionProveedor
     * @return ArticuloDefectuoso
     */
    public function setDevolucionProveedor(\CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\DevolucionProveedor $devolucionProveedor = null)
    {
        $this->devolucionProveedor = $devolucionProveedor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get devolucionProveedor
     *
     * @return \CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\DevolucionProveedor 
     */
    public function getDevolucionProveedor()
    {
        return $this->devolucionProveedor;
    }

#DevolucionProveedor


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\ArticuloDefectuoso", mappedBy="devolucionProveedor", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $articulosDefectuosos;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->articulosDefectuosos = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
     //methods


    /**
     * Add articulosDefectuosos
     *
     * @param \CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\ArticuloDefectuoso $articulosDefectuosos
     * @return DevolucionProveedor
     */
    public function addArticulosDefectuoso(\CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\ArticuloDefectuoso $articulosDefectuosos)
    {
        $articulosDefectuosos->setDevolucionProveedor($this);
        $this->articulosDefectuosos[] = $articulosDefectuosos;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove articulosDefectuosos
     *
     * @param \CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\ArticuloDefectuoso $articulosDefectuosos
     */
    public function removeArticulosDefectuoso(\CeiferIT\VentasAlmacenBundle\Entity\ArticuloDefectuoso $articulosDefectuosos)
    {
        $this->articulosDefectuosos->removeElement($articulosDefectuosos);
    }

    /**
     * Get articulosDefectuosos
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getArticulosDefectuosos()
    {
        return $this->articulosDefectuosos;
    }
```

My controller:

```
public function nuevoAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $devolucionProveedor = new DevolucionProveedor();
        $formulario = $this->createForm(new DevolucionProveedorType(), $devolucionProveedor, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('devolucionesProveedor_nuevo'),
            'attr' => array(
                'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
            ),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $formulario->handleRequest($request);

        if($formulario->isValid()){
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'exito',
                'Nueva devolucion anadida correctamente'
            );
            $em->persist($devolucionProveedor);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("devolucionesProveedor_index"));
        }

        return $this->render('VentasAlmacenBundle:DevolucionesProveedor:nuevo.html.twig', array(
            "formulario" => $formulario->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have an error message when you launch: `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Comment: Where are you adding `ArticuloDefectuoso` to your `DevolucionProveedor`. I don't see this in your code.

Comment: @Wilt in the method addArticulosDefectuoso i setter DevolucionProveedor in articuloDefectuoso entity

Comment: @scoolnico yes i dont get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to persist the entity on the owning side to make this work. In your case this means you have to explicitly call `persist` on the `$articulosDefectuosos` that you are adding.
Check [the doctrine 2 documentation here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts) for more information.

> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored. Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)

Comment: Oh, thank you! i have add a foreach in my controller, foreach $devolucion->getArticulosDefectuosos as $articulo, and $articulo->setDevolucionProveedor($devolucion) and this work, thank!

Comment: Could you update your question with your foreach code?  You really should not have to call persist on each $articulosDefectuosos.  Maybe I am just not understanding your comment.

Comment: @Cerad You should direct your comment at Ivan. I don't think he will get notified when you leave a comment at my answer. At least not without a @ annotation